PostgreSQL on Windows: can't delete database
I have several databases on PostgreSQL under W11 pro.
I want to delete some of them but it returns error.
I started the PSQL.exe into a CMD instance ran as Administrator.
For instance I want to delete the first: Backingratcks (which is mistakenly written) and Backingtracks
I give the command DROP DATABASE Backingratcks; to remove the first one,
but it returns a not specified error and it doesn't delete the database.
I just followed the PostgreSQL instructions from the manual.
Exactly the same it occurs when I want to delete "Backingtracks", "Noises", "TEST", "cs" etc.
Where am I wrong please?



Read  Identifiers, especially the part about how to deal with case sensitivity.

Use double quotes " around the database name: DROP DATABASE "Backingratcks";. And never use upper case again...

Does this answer your question? Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?. Just one of the many answers to this question.

@FrankHeikens we posted at the same time. Indeed I did use teh quotes and while i was writing the solution you also wrote. It worked indeed.

The solution is to put the database name in double quotes.
DROP DATABASE Backingratcks; Didn't work
DROP DATABASE "Backingratcks"; Worked perfectly
